# getting variables from an array where some variables are arrays

Tags: php, arrays

I am struggling of getting values extracted from an array where some values are values and some values are arrays.

```
global $globals;

foreach($globals as $value)
    {
    if ($value == "array")
        {
        global $$value = array;
        }
      else
        {
        global $$value;
        }
    }
```

Everything is fine except this part: `global $$value = array;` How to foreach `$value` as array?

Comment: What in the world are you trying to do in general?  This is completely unnecessary, ever.

Comment: What are you doing? Using every $value of the $globals as Variablename???

Comment: One Hint `$value == "array"` is done in PHP like `is_array($array)` if you want to check if the given value is an array.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you could make use of the PHP is_array function ?

http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-array.php

e.g.

```
if(is_array($value)) {
    echo 'Is Array';
} else {
    echo 'not an Array';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're trying to accomplish is to check if any $value in the $globals is array or not, for that you may use `is_array` and use for each as per your needs.

```
foreach($globals as $value)
{
    if (is_array($value)){
        foreach ($value as $new_value) {
            # Your job
        }
    }
    //
    //other codes
}
```